# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null for FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting error while rendering XML file.
It has FragmentTabHost, TabWidget with Vertical ScrollView and FrameLayout for displaying tab's content. And ya I am using vertical tabs over horizontal.

Below is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </ScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <com.custom.FontButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@color/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_height"
            android:text="CLEAR"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_18"
            app:customFont="@string/font_regular" />

        <com.custom.FontButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_apply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_height"
            android:text="APPLY"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_18"
            app:customFont="@string/font_regular" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the error it is throwing while rendering -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2836)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:232)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

PS: I have read other post, but none of them are working, so please don't mark this as duplicate.

**EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND**

The problem is with `FragmentTabHost` is that by default orientation is set to `TabWidget.HORIZONTAL` and it cannot be modified via XML, which is why `IllegalStateException` occurred for `VERTICAL` scrolls.
To overcome this in `Fragment` or `Activity` class we need to set orientation manually. Check out the snippet for setting orientation

```
TabWidget.setOrientation(TabWidget.VERTICAL);
```

once done you are done with the error!